# Vulnerable to Intent Redirection

Tags: android-security

I have recently published my Android App to the Playstore and I have received the below email from Google Play console.

We reviewed your App and found that your app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users. Apps with these vulnerabilities can expose user information or damage a user’s device, and may be considered to be in violation of our Malicious Behavior policy.

**Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection.**

I am using the SMS Retriever API in my App for Reading the SMS- I have used one time consent to read the SMS using below link.

[https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/request][1]

I have also added the exported="false" to the particular Activity in AndroidManifest. still the issue is not resolved.

If anyone has solution for this please let me know, Your help will be highly appeciated.

Comment: @user:4898360 have you found any solution? As we use user consent API then we do not need to register receiver of SMS broadcast in the manifest file but it gives Intent Redirection vulnerability issue but if we use SMS Retrieval API then we have to add a receiver in the manifest file and the Intent redirection issue also get resolved but we can't read SMS without prefix and package name & certificate.